# IntelliJ IDEA + Gradle - How can I log a long running Gradle task run from the IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, task, long-running-processes

IntelliJ IDEA sometimes takes a long time to do a Gradle refresh task or run a Gradle task. It will just kinda spin for a long time leaving you wondering how far along it is or if it's even doing anything at all or frozen?

For example this has been running for a long time:

[image: intellij screenshot for run tasks]

But I have no way to see what is happening? Where are the logs?

Here is a long running refresh:

[image: intellij screenshot for long running refresh project]

Comment: There is an open feature request to see Gradle output: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157505. Try building from the command line to see what's taking so long.

Comment: yeah that's what i did to get going again i just was wondering if there was a way to get the logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to get the logs from IntelliJ IDEA when Gradle project is imported/refreshed, please vote for the feature request:

- [IDEA-157505](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157505) View Gradle output when importing project